# String having xml kind of value, how can I fetch key to update missing value?

Tags: java, xml, string

I have a long string value. Here some `values` are missing as you see `verifyoName`. I wanted to fetch this `key` and add `value` for this key and finally update the payload with values. Could you please give
me some idea how can I do it.

```
        String msg=<aleri:MESSAGE 
        xmlns:aleri="http://www.aleri.com/2005/JS/aleri"><HEADER> 
        <OPCODE>Capture</OPCODE></HEADER><DATA><Operators Branch="21" 
        Profile="ABC" VerifyDateTime="" VerifyoName="" /></DATA></aleri:MESSAGE>
```

Comment: Will your string be like this (adding scape char \ and "):  String msg= "<aleri:MESSAGE xmlns:aleri=\"http://www.aleri.com/2005/JS/aleri\"><HEADER> <OPCODE>Capture</OPCODE></HEADER><DATA><Operators Branch=\"21\" Profile=\"ABC\" VerifyDateTime=\"\" VerifyoName=\"\" /></DATA></aleri:MESSAGE>";

Comment: Actully i m getting this string by using this line
String msg = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(record.get("RawMessage").toString());

Comment: *Some idea how to do it:* 1) Parse the XML, 2) update the data, 3) render back to XML.

Comment: could u please help me to parse this xml.